# Stripe multiple subscriptions at checkout best method?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am using Stripe and have a site (node, express, react) where customers purchase subscriptions. They can purchase multiple subscriptions at a time and those subscriptions can have varying intervals. So, each subscription is created separately on the back end during checkout. Basically, the back end receives an array of subscription criteria for the customer's cart and sets up each one as its own subscription, returning an array of subscription objects.

Here is the possible issue I am realizing. Let's say there are 5 subscriptions in a customer's cart it is possible that 3 subscriptions are created successfully and that 2 fail due to insufficient funds, or other reasons. Now you have a partially completed checkout, the card has already been charged for 3 subscriptions and you need new payment details for the remaining 2 subscriptions. Plus, you have to handle letting the user know and altering the cart to reflect that only some of the cart has been purchased which I'm not sure what the expected UI/UX for something like that is. Anyone have any ideas on how to handle this better with Stripe to charge all or none or something similar.

Comment: I have a different concern is that how would your customers card handle up to 5 rapid charges for subscriptions? For safety sake having them be done individually would be a better experience here and safer to keep you out of potential fraud status

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that one as well. Might have to tell the client we need to do it differently.

Comment: The last thing your client would want is to be flagged as fraud on Stripe

Comment: This does sound like a nightmare of an experience from the user's point of view, let alone trying to implement it. Multiple subscriptions with different payment methods in one checkout is hard to justify.